# Import the data from the local machine to the Google cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I want to ingest the data from local machine to the google cloud storage, there are a lot of files on the local machine, so I was trying the command:
gsutil cp - r /Users/marc/Documents/Documentation/Tables.xlsx gs://testing_bucketzz

gsutil cp - r "/Users/marc/Documents/Documentation/Tables.xlsx" gs://testing_bucketzz

I get the error -  No such file or directory

Another approach that I tried:
gcloud cloud-shell scp localhost:~/Users/marc/Documents/Documentation/Tables.xlsx cloudshell:~/table.xlsx

Getting the error:
ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to load files from your local physical machine via cloud shell? if you want to lift files from your local machine with gsutil you need to install the sdk on your local machine or upload those files to the cloud shell machine as cloudshell is a remote vm that is agnostic of the existance of your local machine

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

> Use the -r option to copy an entire directory tree.

Your example shows you are trying to copy a single `.xlxs` file. Try it without the `-r` option.